# Firebase Analytics events with Expo not firing on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, google-analytics, expo, firebase-analytics

I have implemented Analytics events using Firebase Analytics in a React Native app using Expo.
The setup works fine with Android and I can even see that my Firebase Dashboard detects my iOS users, meaning the connection of the app to firebase console seems to be working fine. The problem is, I cannot see any of the events fired from iOS devices.

This is how my App.json looks like:

```
{
    "expo": {
        "ios": {
            "bundleIdentifier": "dk.xxx.xxxApp",
            "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
            "config": {
                "googleMapsApiKey": "xxxxxxxxx"
            }
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./assets/icon.png",
            "config": {
                "firebase": {
                    "apiKey": "xxx",
                    "authDomain": "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
                    "projectId": "xxx",
                    "storageBucket": "xxx.appspot.com",
                    "messagingSenderId": "xxx",
                    "appId": "1:1234567:web:1234567890",
                    "measurementId": "G-xxx"
                }
            }
        },
        "android": {
            "package": "dk.xxx.xxxApp",
            "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
            "permissions": ["CAMERA", "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"],
            "config": {
                "googleMaps": {
                    "apiKey": "xxx"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of an event I am firing:

```
    Analytics.logEvent('trip', {
        trip_state: 'start',
        status: 'failure',
        error: error?.ErrorCode,
        start_loc: startLocation,
    });
```

This is my platform breakdown in Google Analytics:

[image: Google analytics platform breakdown]

And finally, when viewing events in BigQuery, I can see that I have thousands of events being fired from a device where platform="ANDROID" while none of my events have a platform="IOS". What could be the reason and solution for these events not being tracked on iOS devices?